# Formula to determine transparancy

Tags: c, colors, bitmap, pixel, bmp

Say you want to put pixel with a color (R0 G200 B255) in a BMP picture and you have `transp` option in percents.

How do I determine the new pixel color, considering the `transp` and the background color?

---

I actually could figure out a formula that looks promising:

```
newpixel = newpixel + (bgpixel * transp) / %(transp of 255)
```

I created it by analyzing the pixel color change in GIMP. Not sure if that is the correct formula. I think it is also rounded up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard formula is `pixel = new_pixel * alpha + pixel * (1 - alpha)`, where *alpha* is a number between *0* and *1* that describes the opacity of the new (foreground) pixel.

You'll note that if the new pixel is fully transparent (`alpha = 0`) the pixel is unchanged and that if the new pixel is fully opaque (`alpha = 1`) the new pixel replaces the old one.

This formula must be applied separately for each pixel components (red, green and blue).

Answer (score 0):

the code needs to change to 24 bit pixels.

where the 4th byte is the transparency factor.

The actual color values do not change

Comment: No, there is no need for 4th byte for that. This is not real transparency, but a modification of the new pixel influenced by the old one. Also you probably meant 32 bits*